# Is there any way to store a scipy integration as a function?

Tags: numpy, parallel-processing, scipy

I am stuck with a problem when I need to compute an integration and run the loop for thousands of times.

The prototype of this function would be:

```py
func_integrated = lambda t: scipy.integrate.quad(func, t, 1)
```

but then if I want to feed `func_integrated` into an array, that means I'll have to run this integration thousands of time, which is not very efficient. After all, the series from `t` to `t-dt` is just approximately `func(t) *dt`.

My guess would be to write something like this:

```py
def function_integration(func, arr):
    arr = np.flip(arr, 0) # flip to count form back to front
    out_arr = np.array([0])
    for i in range(1,len(arr)):
        increment = arr[i-1] -arr[i]
        out_arr = np.hstack((out_arr, increment * func(arr[i-1])))
    return np.cumsum(out_arr)
```

However this is not generic, and still needs looping. I was wondering if there is any `scipy` or `numpy` way to handle this more efficiently.

P.S. I am aware of the `sympy` approach. However that relies heavily on built-in functions, so the method can hardly be generally adapted.

Comment: list append is more efficient than repeated hstack.  Can you write `func` so it takes an array of points instead of just one at a time?

Comment: So you want to do the integral over a set of ranges.  `quad` is good for one range, choosing the optimal integration interval, etc.  But if you can get by with evaluating `func` at a known set of values, then some version of your `cumsum` should be better.  Even better if `func` can be evaluated at all integration value with one call.  Calling `func` iteratively is slower.

Comment: You could sort your array, and call `quad` on successive intervales, and accumulate those.  `quad` takes a `points` parameter, but apparently doesn't return an integral at those points.  I don't know if one of the other integrators does return those or not.

Comment: You have to evaluate the function at each of the array values.  But do you also need to evaluate it at in between points to get good enough accuracy?  Something like `quad` takes care of the accuracy issue for you.  There's a trade off between the accuracy and cost of evaluating the function many times.